# Scilab polarplot of multiple functions does not use different colors for every graph

Tags: plot, graph, scilab, calculus, polar-coordinates

I'm trying to plot two different polar functions in the same graph, but with different color.

Here's my code:

```
clear
close
clc
clf
theta=[0:((1*%pi)/180):((359*%pi)/180)];
a=2;
b=3;
rho=a+b*sin(theta);
rro=a-b*sin(theta);
polarplot([theta theta], [real(rho) real(rro)],[27 14]);
xtitle("Caracol con lazo interior");
legends(['r = a+bsen(θ)';'r = a-bsen(θ)'],[27 14],opt=3);
```

And although the graphs are plotted properly, it only uses the first defined color for both. In this case: 27

[image: Result graph]

So, I want one to be orange and the other green.

Can you please tell me how to fix the issue, please? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code `theta` is a row vector, and therefore `rho` and `rro` are also row vectors. So when you combine them as `[theta theta], [real(rho) real(rro)]` the result is **one curve** obtained by concatenating the two curves. Of course it is plotted with one color. The fix is to make `theta` a column vector:

```
theta=[0:((1*%pi)/180):((359*%pi)/180)]';
```

Then `[theta theta]` and `[real(rho) real(rro)]` are matrices with two columns, and the result is as expected; two colors for two curves.

Comment: Wow, I didn't know it was that simple. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Alternatively with your original theta: `polarplot([theta' theta'], [real(rho)' real(rro)'],[27 14]);`